# Conditional Excel Formula: "If" cell contents are a value that refers to a png file

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a conditional 'If' formula in excel. If a cell contains the value WhiteBall.png, I want the cell next to it be populated with "win" (or "Lose" if it does not.

I cannot get the formula to work. I'm using Excel 2011 for Mac. Please see below. Thanks for your help.

```
=IF(E4=WhiteBall.png,”Win”,”Lose”)
```

I have also tried this formula:

```
=IF(E4="WhiteBall.png",”Win”,”Lose”)
```

Comment: your second formula looks correct.  There may be a trailing or leading space...or both.  Try putting your E4 in TRIM() and/or CLEAN().  `=IF(TRIM(CLEAN(E4))="WhiteBall.png",”Win”,”Lose”)`

Comment: Thanks Forward Ed. No extra spaces. With the formula your proposed, I get a #Name error just as I did with mine. I'm thinking it might have something to do with the fact that it's referring to an image file - .png

Comment: E4 is also the outcome of a formula. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Retype the second formula from scratch in a new cell.  the quotes `”` are not the ones recognized by Excel.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I have just retyped it as follows:     =IF(E5="WhiteBall.png","Win","Lose")    It will not calculate.

Comment: On the Mac, there is one function for quotation marks,  not two...as I think the formula may require.

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

=IF(E4="WhiteBall.png","Win","Lose")
[see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPbPS.png)